# How to quotient modules in homology computation

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory, algebraic-topology, homology-cohomology

I was computing the homology group of a 2-complex with $\mathbb{Z}$ coefficients. Doing so, I obtained
$$
H_1 = \frac{\langle a,b,c,d \rangle}{\langle 2a+2b, 2a+2b+c+d\rangle}
$$
I then tried to simplify the expression for $H_1$ in two different ways. Unfortunately, I obtained two different answers. So at most one (if any) can be correct. I was hoping someone could explain where I went wrong and why my step is incorrect.

First Method:
$$
H_1 = \frac{\langle a,b,c,d \rangle}{\langle 2a+2b, 2a+2b+c+d\rangle}
= \frac{\langle a,b,c,d \rangle}{\langle a = -b, c=-d\rangle}
\cong \mathbb{Z}^2
$$

Second Method: 
$$
H_1 = \frac{\langle a,b,c,d \rangle}{\langle 2a+2b, 2a+2b+c+d\rangle}
\cong \frac{\langle a,a+b,c,c+d \rangle}{\langle 2(a+b), c+d \rangle} \cong \mathbb{Z}_2 \times \mathbb{Z}^2
$$

Comment: That $2u = 0 \implies u = 0$ means your group has no $2$-torsion. So doing that you have quotiented the correct group by its $2$-torsion.

Comment: First method is wrong. Not clear how you got $a=-b$. That isn't a justified manipulation.

Comment: @reuns So the second one is correct?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What element of $\mathbb{Z}$ did you multiply by to cancel the $2$s in $2a + 2b = 0\rightarrow a = -b$?  I'm not familiar with that element of $\mathbb{Z}$.  (If I tell you that, in some group, $a^2 = b^2$, does that mean $a = b$?)

It might be better to think of this as row reduction, using only integer multiplication, of 
$$  \begin{pmatrix}  2 & 2 & 0 & 0 \\ 2 & 2 & 1 & 1 \end{pmatrix}  $$
to get $\langle 2a + 2b, 2a+2b+c+d\rangle = \langle 2(a+b), c+d \rangle$.  Then quotient by that, as you did in your second example (in which, you made the reversible change of basis 
$$  (a,b,c,d) \rightarrow (a,a+b,c,c+d)  $$
to simplify finding your quotient).

Comment: I don't think you can be that hard on OP for deducing $a=-b$ from $2a=-2b$.  If you were in a ring theory class you'd be told that cancellation in $\mathbb{Z}$ is valid even though it has few units.

Comment: @Randall I appreciate you coming to my defense! The $a=-b$ actually came from my course solutions so I'm glad to see that my solution is the correct one

Comment: @MathUser_NotPrime  well, the other issue is that it's **not** an incorrect deduction.  While it may be true that $a^2=b^2 \Rightarrow a=b$ is false in plenty of groups, it **is** true in $\mathbb{Z}$ (interpreted as $2a=2b$ or $a+a=b+b$).

Comment: Yes, I see. Thank you